# Setting an attribute alias for a model

Tags: sails.js

Is it possible to set an alias for a model attribute (column)?

```
//User.js
attributes: {
    favoriteDog: {
        type: 'string',
        alias: 'fav_dog' //in sails console this specific syntax doesn't do anything
    }
}

...

User.find({where: {id: 45}}).exec(function(row) {
    console.log(row.favoriteDog);
    console.log(row.fav_dog); //should get same value
});
```

I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would want to do this. If it is because you want to use a different attribute name in your model than the database column, you can use the `'columnname'` property.

[From the docs:](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes#columnname)

```
// An attribute in one of your models:
// ...
numberOfWheels: {
  type: 'integer',
    columnName: 'number_of_round_rotating_things'
  }
// ...
```